# On testing mailing. System sends two test email Why?

Tags: outbound-email

While sending emails via Mailing. we have to first test the mail. But when I test mail. System sends me two test emails. This doesn't affect my existing functionality but want to know why is it so? Please help me.

Comment: Did I properly answer your question? If so, could you mark it as accepted so that other users might be helped in the future? If you are not satisfied, could you elaborate on what is still missing so that we can provide a fulfilling answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Test Mailing dialog, you choose what E-mail Formats you wish to test.

You should actually receive 3 e-mails:

1. Text-only version
2. HTML-only version
3. Multi-part (which is a combination of the two, which allows the e-mail client to choose the version it wants)

These are all checked by default, since you'll likely want to verify that all versions of the Mailing look good.

Since you only get 2 e-mails, I'm guessing you haven't made a text version of the Mailing. So you're receiving the HTML and Multi-part (with only HTML) versions.

If you know for certain that you will never have any Contacts who accept only accepts text e-mails, that's okay; otherwise, you'll want to create a text version before you send the Mailing. Without it, those Contacts won't receive your Mailing.

For more information, see the following pages of the documentation:

- [Testing a Mailing](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-062A0AE1-AC4A-4985-B2EB-093E6429919D)
- [Separating HTML format and plain-text format](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C590016B-BDFA-4525-8B1C-5C77AA0EA093)